# Is it possible to set a specific FPS cap in google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, settings, nvidia, frame-rate, flicker

I know how to uncap my fps in chrome by pasting --disable-frame-rate-limit into properties. However, when it's uncapped like that the frames fluctuate a lot and it causes flickers when I play browser games. Is it possible to set a custom cap? I capped my frames at 120 (my display is 60) in the nvidia control panel but chrome seems to override this somehow. Help would be much appreciated! :)[image: as you can see its overridden by chrome somehow]